# Issue with virtual environment - python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have an issue with virtual environment, I'm learning python so really do not know what is wrong here.

I have a folder on my desktop called 'learning' in which I am trying to make a virtual environment called venv.

When I am in VSCode I am using the terminal and write `python -m venv venv` which spits out the following:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\learning> virtualenv venv
created virtual environment CPython3.9.5.final.0-64 in 1553ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\learning\venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.1.2, setuptools==57.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
PS C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\learning> python -m venv venv
[{'first': 'Csr', 'last': 'vR'}, {'first': 'Jessie', 'last': 'vdd'}, {'first': 'Bill', 'last': 'Gates'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 22, in <module>
    import collections.abc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'collections.abc'; 'collections' is not a package
PS C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\learning> python -m venv try
[{'first': 'Csr', 'last': 'vR'}, {'first': 'Jessie', 'last': 'vdd'}, {'first': 'Bill', 'last': 'Gates'}]
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 22, in <module>
    import collections.abc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'collections.abc'; 'collections' is not a package
```

As you can see for some reason it is trowing back code from a file called collections.py in the folder 'learning'.. no idea why.
Now when I use "virtualenv venv" it works fine, but I am trying to understand why the other command is not working.

Comment: please edit the question

Comment: Try `python3 -m venv venv`

Comment: Where is that list in your output coming from?

Comment: Also, `python -m venv venv` is supposed to *create* a virtual environment, but you've already created one using `virtualenv`. I suspect `python -m venv` is not executing the `venv` module in the standard library, but some other module you have locally with the same name.

Comment: @waveshaper: this does not help at all. You do not even mention to what I should edit it.

Comment: @William, unfortunately, same issue

Comment: @Chepner it's coming from a python file in the same folder called 'collections.py' I'm not referencing it at all in the command though.
File:csr= {}
csr['first'] = 'Csr'
caspar['last'] = 'vr'

jessie = {}
jessie['first'] = 'Jessie'
jessie['last'] = 'vdd'

people = []
people.append(csr)
people.append(jessie)
people.append({
    'first': 'Bill', 'last':'Gates'
})

print(people)
& I tried python -m venv venv first, had this output then as well

Comment: suggested you to do what @It_is_Chris did, it makes the question more readable.

Comment: @waveshaper I'm fairly new to all of this. From my POV it looks like the edit has gone through, litteraly says this for me:  edited 10 hours ago
It_is_Chris

Is there something I should do?

Comment: @pythonnoobsadly There you go: you are shadowing a module in the standard library. (I wonder if this is triggering a bug; the difference between absolute and relative imports was meant to avoid situations like this.)

Answer (score 1):

You have already created the virtual environment (`venv`). No need to type `python -m venv venv` again.

To activate virtual environment (`venv`), type

```sh
PS C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\learning> venv/Scripts/activate
```

This will activate the virtual environment named `venv` in the powershell.

Comment: Hi,

First of thank you for taking your time to think along :).
I forgot to mention that between the 2 commands I removed the folder, so the virtual environment did not exist anymore when I fired the second command (also got the same output when I tried python -m venv venv the first time without thinking I could use virtualenv venv.

Answer (score 1):

> it's coming from a python file in the same folder called 'collections.py'

That module is somehow shadowing the `collections` module in the standard library. When `typing.py` tries to import `collections.abc`, the import mechanism is finding *your* module named `collections` first, but your module isn't a package that contains a module name `abc`, so you get the error.

The simplest fix would be to rename your own file to something else. However, Python introduced a difference between absolute and relative imports to address conflicts like this. There might be a way to structure your directory to avoid your local module from shadowing the standard library module instead.

`virtualvenv` is entirely different script from the `venv` module; it likely does not try to import the standard `collections` module, so the name collision doesn't affect it.

Comment: You are 100% right my good sir, renamed it to collectionss to test it out and everything works as intended now.
Props to you.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode you may also activate the `venv` by selecting it in the bottom left hand corner. This is an easy reference to confirm which environment you are using.